# how can i identify ajax call to same page

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var temp='getUser';
    $.ajax ({
                type:'GET';
                url: 'listdetails.php?ud=temp';

                success:function(data)
                        {
                            alert(data);
                        }

           });
```

});

By using this jquery , i am calling the same page "listdetails.php"(ie:this jquery is in listdetails.php).This is the code i entered at the begining of the page

```
if($_GET['ud'] =="getUser")
{

    echo "ok";
}
```

When i am loading the page it is showing the error " Notice: Undefined index: ud in C:\wamp\www\listdetails.php on line 8"

ie: variable ud is undefined.How can i avoid this error.I think , if condition need to check only when the page request is ajax,Is it possible to check page request is ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Use `isset`

```
if(isset($_GET['ud']) && $_GET['ud'] =="getUser")
{

    echo "ok";
}
```

To check specifically for AJAX requests, try

`if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')`

But HTTP headers can easily be spoofed.

Comment: How to check the page request is ajax or not

Comment: There is no foolproof way. If you add `?ud=temp` to all AJAX requests, the above method will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You will definetly not get in the if loop for $_GET bcoz the url of ajax is not properly made. I have written the code below, check it

```
var temp='getUser';
$.ajax ({
        type:'GET',
        url: 'listdetails.php?ud='+temp, // your code --- url: 'listdetails.php?ud=temp';

        success:function(data)
        {
              alert(data);
        }

});
```